# How to Prevent Duplicate Calendar (List) Items - SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, list, calendar

I'm trying to create a calendar that will serve as a Conference Room reservation system for my department.

Pain Point: Duplicate reservations are constant.

Needed Solution:  A calendar/list that - when creating a New Item - has the ability to check the existing List Items for duplicate Start Date/Time and End Date/Times.

Use Case to consider: The solution would have to consider any time in between the Start and End times (for example - existing List Item runs from 9am-11am......but someone wants to create a New List item that has a start and end time of 9:30-10:00am ).

Any thoughts how this solution could be built?

Comment: Are you using the Enterprise edition of SharePoint?

Comment: I'm also looking for the same solution for Sharepoint Online 2013.